# Get the child element and modify the text

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I need to toggle the text in the span element from [+] to [-] when the button is clicked with JavaScript. How can I achieve this with my current toggle function?

#### HTML

```
...
<ul>
  ...
  <li>
    <ul>
      <h3>header</h3>
      <a href="#">url-link</a>
      <p>description</p>
    <ul>
    <div class="department" style="display: none;">
      <ul class="placemark"> ... </ul>
      <ul class="contact"> ... </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="department-collapse" onclick="toggle(this)">
      <span>[+]</span> Contact Information
    </button>
  </li>
  ...
<ul>
...
```

#### JavaScript

```
function toggle(self) {
  var n = self.parentNode.childNodes;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i].className == 'department') {
      n[i].style.display = n[i].style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your function, verify your span (JS code):

```
function toggle(self) {
    var n = self.parentNode.childNodes;

    for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        if (n[i].className == 'department') {
            n[i].style.display = n[i].style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
        }
    }

    var mySpan = self.childNodes[0];
    mySpan.innerHTML = mySpan.innerHTML == '[+]' ? '[-]' : '[+]';
}
```

Comment: Using a 0 index doesn't always work. I don't have complete control over the HTML that is being generated, so depending on the result _self.childNodes_ could  return [text, span, text, item: function] or [span, text, function].

Comment: So, change the //self.childNodes[0]// to //self.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]//